# How to enforce foreign keys in NoSql databases (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say I have a collection of documents such as:

```
{ "_id" : 0 , "owner":0 "name":"Doc1"},{ "_id" : 1 , "owner":1, "name":"Doc1"}, etc
```

And, on the other hand the owners are represented as a separate collection:

```
{ "_id" : 0 , "username":"John"}, { "_id" : 1 , "username":"Sam"}
```

How can I make sure that, when I insert a document it references the user in a correct way. In old-school RDBMS this could easily be done using a Foreign Key.

I know that I can check the correctness of insertion from my business code, BUT what if an attacker tampers with my request to the server and puts "owner" : 100, and Mongo doesn't throw any exception back.

I would like to know how this situation should be handled in a real-word application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If an attacker could tamper with your request, what makes you think they couldn't tamper with the responding exception?

Comment: I have posted a solution to this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402942/there-is-a-way-to-enforce-referential-integrity-in-mongodb/56410944#56410944

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't have foreign keys (as you have presumably noticed). Fundamentally the answer is therefore, "Don't let users tamper with the requests. Only let the application insert data that follows your referential integrity rules."

MongoDB is great in lots of ways... but if you find that you need foreign keys, then it's probably not the correct solution to your problem.

Answer (score 15):

To answer your specific question - while MongoDB encourages handling foreign-key relationships on the client side, they also provide the idea of "Database References" - See [this help page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References).

That said, *I don't recommend using a DBRef*. Either let your client code manage the associations or (better yet) link the documents together from the start. You may want to consider embedding the owner's "documents" inside the owner object itself. Assemble your documents to match your usage patterns and MongoDB will shine.

Answer (score 5):

This is a one-to-one to relationship. It's better to embed one document in another, instead of maintaining separate collections. Check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/) on how to model them in mongodb and their advantages.

Although its not explicitly mentioned in the docs, embedding gives you the  same effect as foreign key constraints. Just want to make this idea clear. When you have two collections like that:

C1:

```
{ "_id" : 0 , "owner":0 "name":"Doc1"},{ "_id" : 1 , "owner":1, "name":"Doc1"}, etc
```

C2:

```
{ "_id" : 0 , "username":"John"}, { "_id" : 1 , "username":"Sam"}
```

And if you were to declare foreign key constraint on `C2._id` to reference `C1._id` (assuming MongoDB allows it), it would mean that you cannot insert a document into `C2` where `C2._id` is non-existent in `C1`. Compare this with an embedded document:

```
{
    "_id" : 0 , 
    "owner" : 0,
    "name" : "Doc1",
    "owner_details" : {
        "username" : "John"
    }
}
```

Now the owner_details field represents the data from the C2 collection, and the remaining fields represent the data from C1. You can't add an owner_details field to a non-existent document. You're essentially achieving the same effect.

Comment: Let's clarify.
C1 is a table of documents, each of them having an owner.
C2 is a table of owners.
The relationship between them is many-to-one, C1 (many) to C2 (one).

Comment: @StanislavKarakhanov, I assumed it was a one to one relationship! This blog has served me well for modelling one-to-many relationships in MongoDB

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Answer (score 2):

This questions was originally answered in 2011, so I decided to post an update here.

Starting from version MongoDB 4.0 (released in  June 2018), it started [supporting multi-document ACID transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions).

Relations now can be modeled in [two approaches](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_relationships.htm):

- Embedded
- Referenced (NEW!)

You can model referenced relationship like so:

```json
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
   "contact": "987654321",
   "dob": "01-01-1991",
   "name": "Tom Benzamin",
   "address_ids": [
      ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000")
   ]
}
```

Where the sample document structure of address document:

```json
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000"),
   "building": "22 A, Indiana Apt",
   "pincode": 123456,
   "city": "Los Angeles",
   "state": "California"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone really wants to enforce the Foreign keys in the Project/WebApp. Then you should with a MixSQL approach i.e. SQL + NoSQL

I would prefer that the Bulky data which doesn't have that much references then it can be stored in NoSQL database Store. Like : Hotels or Places type of data.

But if there is some serious things like OAuth modules Tables, TokenStore and UserDetails and UserRole (Mapping Table) etc.... then you can go with SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I would also reccommend that if username's are unique, then use them as the _id. You will save on an index. In the document being stored, set the value of 'owner' in the application as the value of 'username' when the document is created and never let any other piece of code update it.

If there are requirements to change the owner, then provide appropirate API's with business rules implemented.

There woudln't be any need of foreign keys.

Comment: Except, if you do this, if a user wants to change his username, you have to delete the existing record and then insert a new one with the changed username.