# What is a better way to prevent document from deleting if a reference is present in another document in Mongodb via Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am creating a webapp using the following stack:

- Node
- Express
- MongoDB
- Mongoose

I have structured the app into a MVC structure.

There are Customer, OrderReceived and OrderSent schemas. OrderReceived and OrderSent schema references Customer schema. Abridge schema structures are following:

Customer

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  companyName: String,
  firstName: { type: String, required: true},
  lastName: { type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);
```

OrderReceived

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderReceivedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  receivedDate: { type: Date, required: true},
  customer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer', required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderReceived', orderReceivedSchema);
```

OrderSent

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  sentDate: { type: Date, required: true},
  customer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer', required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderSent', orderSentSchema);
```

When a Customer document is asked for delete, I want to check if it the document is referenced by either OrderReceived or OrderSent documents. And if there is a presence I want to prevent the deletion of the Customer document.

The solution I came up with is to do the check in the controller of Customer, as following:

CustomerController#destroy this handles the delete request:

```
destroy(req, res){
    OrderReceived.count({customer: req.params.id}, (error, orderLength)=>{
      if (error) res.send(error);
      if (orderLength<1){
        OrderSent.count({'customer.customer': req.params.id}, (error, orderLength)=>{
          if (error) res.send(error);
          if (orderLength<1){
            Customer.remove({_id: req.params.id}, error => {
              if (error) res.send(error);
              res.json({message: 'Customer successfully deleted.'});
            });
          } else {
            res.status(409).json({message: 'There are orders sent using the Customer. Datum could not be deleted'});
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(409).json({message: 'There are orders received using the Customer. Datum could not be deleted.'});
      }
    });
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have other models that also depends upon the Customer document and this code is only going to get messier. 
Please help.

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914262/how-to-restrict-delete-in-mongodb-for-relationship-collection/39916241#39916241

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating `OrderReceived` or `OrderSent` save reference of it in `Customer` too.
So on this way before you delete it, you can simply check if they are empty or not.
Your Customer schema would be like:

```
const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    firstName: { type: String, required: true},
    lastName: { type: String, required: true},
    ordersSent: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OrderSent'}],
    ordersReceived: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OrderReceived'}],
});
```

and your delete function should contain something like:

```
Customer.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(customer => {
        if(customer.ordersSent.length== 0&& customer.ordersReceived.length== 0)
            return true
        //if there was more than 0
        return false
    }).then(result => {
        if(result)
            return Customer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
        res.status(409).json({message: 'There are orders received or sent using the Customer. Customer could not be deleted.'})
    }).then(customerDataJustInCase =>{
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Customer deleted.'})
    }).catch(err => {
        //your error handler
    })
```

or you can use it via try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Promise.all** method to perform all DB queries at once, like below:

```
Promise.all([
  OrderReceived.count({customer: req.params.id}),
  OrderSent.count({'customer.customer': req.params.id})
])
  .then(([orderReceivedCount, orderSendCount]) => {
    if (orderReceivedCount < 1 && orderSendCount<1) { 
      ...delete doc 
    }
   }).catch(error => ...handleError)
```